# Move the sharepoint export list to excel button out of the ribbon

Tags: printing, export-to-excel, sharepoint-list, sharepointfoundation2010

I am working with SharePoint Foundation 2010 to create an external facing site, allowing anonymous users to view most pages and lists.

On one of my pages there is a list that I would like my anonymous users to be able to export to excel (for printing purposes). However my problem is that I have hidden my ribbon completely from anonymous users (for obvious styling reasons) and do not intend for them to be able to view it.

Is there any way to move the "Export to Excel" button from the ribbon to the page, or any other way to create a control on the page that can export the list?

In the end, my main goal is to be able to let anonymous users print just the displayed list without having to print the entire page.